# Rails MySQL subquery count

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, count, subquery

I have two models:

1. Product
2. Click

I would like to get all products that have more than x clicks.

The tables looks like this:

```
Products

id
```

,

```
Clicks

id | product_id
```

In ruby, the code might look like `products.select {|p| p.clicks.size > x}`.  How might one write a similar query for mysql?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just asking how to write SQL to perform this query? Or are you asking how to do it in ActiveRecord/Rails land?

Comment: In the end, I'll be writing it in Rails ARel.  So that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE Id IN
(
    SELECT 
        P.Id
    FROM Products P
       JOIN Clicks C
          ON P.Id = C.Product_ID
    GROUP BY P.ID
    HAVING COUNT(1) > x
) A
```

or this, if you need only product id

```
    SELECT 
        P.Id
    FROM Products P
       JOIN Clicks C
          ON P.Id = C.Product_ID
    GROUP BY P.ID
    HAVING COUNT(1) > x
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this efficiently, you may want to look into using a counter cache. ActiveRecord has built in support for this concept, and it will keep you from having to do a subquery.

Some links:

- [Blog Tutorial](http://hiteshrawal.blogspot.com/2011/12/rails-counter-cache.html)
- [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=asciicast)
- [Rails Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)